# CSS in Vue.js app: Safari & Firefox are not loading Google Font

Tags: css, vue.js, firefox, fonts, safari

I'm making a portfolio with Vue. I would like the global font style to be Montserrat, but Chrome is the only browser that's reflecting the CSS. Both Safari and Firefox are throwing errors in the inspector saying that they can't reach Google Fonts url.

I've tried using @import syntax, font-face syntax, and href links in the HTML. I also tried downloading the fonts and hosting them in my Vue app, but I can't seem to get it to work -- I'm still new with Vue.

Currently:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? family=Montserrat:400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

This can get Chrome to show the correct font. If I pull the URL and paste it into either Firefox or Safari, both will be unable to load the page. When opening the inspector, both show that they can't load the resource from fonts.google.

In App.vue style section:

```
#app {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  font-family:'Montserrat', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

I have also tried to swap the HTML with:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  src: url('/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'),
   url('/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
   url('/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
```

and I have also tried the basic:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400&display=swap');
```

Nothing has worked. You can literally paste

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400&display=swap
```

into Chrome & you can see the font selectors, but in Firefox & Safari you can't even load the page.

I expected the Montserrat font in Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, but I only see it rendering in Chrome.

Comment: Is the space after the `?` really in your URL or just in the question? For me it works fine in Firefox if I just remove that space. If that isn't the problem could you please include the full error message in the question?

Comment: @skirtle That was just a typing error in my post, not the code. In both Safari and Firefox inspectors I get a message like "Failed to load resource. Could not connect to the 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' server"

Comment: Sounds more like a networking/proxy issue than a code problem. Are you able to access https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat from Firefox & Safari?

Comment: @skirtle Firefox & Safari are working fine otherwise on my laptop. But I notice in Safari on my iPhone just now the link you provide doesn't work, but it does in Chrome for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Conflicts in the host file prevent Google fonts from loading in non-Chrome browsers, or from relaying fonts to other devices when acting as local host.